# Is it true constructor's prototype cannot overwrite public members?

Tags: javascript

Example 1:

```
function Cat(){
    this.color = function (){
        return "Green";
    };
}

Cat.prototype.color = function(){
    return "Blue";
}

var kitty = new Cat();
alert(kitty.color()); // Green
```

Example 2:

```
function Cat(){
    var color = function (){
        return "Green";
    };
}

Cat.prototype.color = function(){
    return "Blue";
}

var kitty = new Cat();
alert(kitty.color()); // Blue
```

Example 2 returns `Blue`, is it because the constructor cannot overwrite public members or it cannot access private members?

Comment: Example 2 is flawed because `var color = function () ...` doesn't actually attach a `color` function to `Cat`.

Comment: I thought it was not flaw http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: This what happens when you tell people "private" variables exist. They don't. `color` is a local variable

Comment: To understand why Example 1 works the way it does, you need to  understand JS scope chains and identifier resolution. Start with [this (warning, PDF link)](http://yuiblog.com/assets/High_Perf_JavaScr_Ch2.pdf) (the section titled _"Scope Chains and Identifier Resolution"_ should suffice) and [this](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clIdRes).

Comment: @Raynos: wouldn't that be a matter of semantics?

Comment: @Kooilnc of course not. And this will cause big problems in terms of terminology with ES6 instance variables which are true private variables.

Comment: @Matt Ball : Thanks for the links

Comment: @Raynos: please explain why color from the second example can't be called private then? Or point me to a link supporting your point of view?

Comment: @Kooilnc there is no notion of private, it's a local variable. The entire concept of private doesn't exist in ES5. You can call it "private" if you want to be treated like a Java programmer who's trying to learn JS and needs to use familiar terminology.

Comment: @Raynos: this is not ES5. The `color` variable is local. And it's only accessible in it's own scope. And it can be removed without influencing anything in a program. Yes. It's local. And it looks pretty private too. Anyway, I'm curious as to ES5's lack of the notion of privateness. How would we program with it, baring in mind what is stated in this article: http://typicalprogrammer.com/?p=23?

Comment: @Kooilnc String search for `private` in the ES5.1 specification. All it is, is a future reserved keyword. The notion has _no meaning_ in ES5. What you call "private" I call local. There is simply _no need_ to give it the fake name "private".

Comment: @Raynos: *What you call "private" I call local*. You've answered my initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example 2 does nothing to `color` within the constructor, because it's not a property but a function within it's scope. For example 1 you should realize that the lookup of properties starts with local properties, if nothing is found there it continues to prototype properties. So in the case of example 1 the local `color`-method is found first and executed. The local and prototype methods are different methods, as may be demonstrated in:

```
function Cat(){
    this.color = function (){
        return Cat.prototype.color ? Cat.prototype.color() : "Green";
    };
}

Cat.prototype.color = function(){
    return "Blue";
}

var prrr = new Cat;
alert(prrr.color()); //=> Blue
```

So in that sense the answer to your question is: yes. But not in:

```
function Cat(){
    this.color = function (){
        return Cat.prototype.color ? Cat.prototype.color() : "Green";
    };
}
Cat.prototype.color = function(){
    if (this.color && !this.colorOverwritten) {
        this.color = function(){return "Orange";};
        this.colorOverwritten = true;
    }
    return "Blue";
}

var prrr = new Cat;
alert(prrr.color()); //=> Blue
alert(prrr.color()); //=> Orange
```